# Kettle Pentaho backup transformation by latest data

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I need to sychronize some data from a database to another using kettle/spoon transformation. The logic is i need to select latest date data that has existed in destination db. Then select from source db from the last date. What transformation element do i need to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a timestamp column in the destination and the source tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many solutions:

1. If you have timestamp columns in both the source and destination tables, then you can take two table input steps. In the first one, just select the max last updated timestamp, use it as a variable in the next table input, taking it as a filter for the source data. You can do something like this:
   [image]
2. If you just want the new data to be updated in the destination table and you don't care much about timestamp, I would suggest you to use insert/update step for output. It will bring all the data to the stream and if it finds a match, it won't insert anything. If it doesn't find a match, it will insert the new row. If it finds any modifications to the existing row in the destination table, it will update it accordingly.

Comment: I use pdi version 6. The data is growing and i need to filter it. How to use table input as a variable for other table input? I know that we can use parameterized query by using '?' but i don't know how. Do you have example in fiddle or screen capture?